# old bug has returned, Participant Role on Event's Schedule Reminder form does not populate

Tags: civievent, message-templates

this bug has returned in the latest 4.7.x (verified on 4.7.17 and .16) https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-13309

if you have a scheduled reminder for an event you can not select to restrict by participant role because the options don't show up

for now I'm working around this by editing the event templates directly in the db